# Can we solve a random ordinary differential equation with any type of noise?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, random-variables

I want to solve a scalar differential equation with a random forcing drawn from a power law distribution. It looks like
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t) + \sigma(x,t) \eta_t
$$
where $\eta$ represents a power-law noise term that is bounded and always positive.

How can I solve the equation numerically?

Comment: No differently than you would solve the same SDE using white noise (Wiener process). There is a book by Kloeden and Platen that describes various discretization schemes.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to do this when the noise term has a nonzero mean. Doing the simple Euler-Maruyama recursion, $x_{i+1} = x_i + f(x_i,t) \Delta t + \sqrt{\Delta t} \sigma(x_i,t) \eta_t$, gives results that depend on the step size. Any pointers?

Comment: I know the mean of the noise term, so I could just subtract it out